# Cant call ParametizedThread from Child Form

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, tcpclient, tcpserver

I am developing a Client/server app.
In the Client app, I have a Main Form that is an MDI parent.
The Main Form has a Load event that creates a new instance of a Child Form and makes it visible.
This event also establishes Main as the MdiParent of Child.
The Child form is meant to be a sign-in screen.
From the child form, I create a reference to the parent, to be able to call methods from the parent.

However, upon executing the MdiParent.RequestConnection method, the GUI becomes stuck.
So I tried to execute the method from a Thread, but it is not accepting my declaration, even if I'm seemingly following the correct syntax.
I don't see what am I doing wrong. Please help

Main form

```
public partial class frmMainForm: Form
    {
        
        public frmMainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
           
        }
        Thread runningClient;
        public MyTcpClient client= new MyTcpClient ();
        frmChildForm frmSignIn;
        bool clientConnected;
       

        private void frmMainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            clientConnected= false;
            panelSidebar.Hide();
            if(frmSignIn == null)
            {
                frmSignIn= new frmChildForm();
                frmSignIn.MdiParent = this;
                
                frmSignIn.Show();
            }
        }

        public void TurnOnPanels()
        {
            panelSidebar.Visible = true;
            panelSidebar.BringToFront();
        }

        public void RequestConnection(string username)
        {
            
            string serverRsp = client.Connect(username);
            if(serverRsp.Equals("SUCCESS")) 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Signed In", "Welcome", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                clientConnected = true;
                frmSignIn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

And my child form

```
public partial class frmChildForm : Form
    {
        frmMainForm frmParent;
        Thread clientRunning;
        public frmChildForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            frmParent= (frmMainForm)this.MdiParent;
        }

        private void frmSignIn_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            frmParent= (frmMainForm)this.MdiParent;
            frmParent.TurnOnPanels();
        }

        private void btnSignIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtSignInUsername.Text.Equals(""))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No empty fields.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            } 
            else
            {
                //This is where it fails
                clientRunning= new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(frmParent.RequestConnection);
                //"No Overload for RequestConnection matches delegate ParameterizedThreadStart"
                //If I try to include the parameter inside that call, I get a "waiting for method                      //name" syntax error message instead.
                clientRunning.Start(txtSignInUsername.Text.ToUpper());
            }
        }

        private void frmSignIn_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            frmParent = (frmMainForm)this.MdiParent;
        }
    }
```

I also tried to do it from the main form by creating a thread inside RequestConnection, where it was supposed to execute client.Connect, but I got the same error.

Comment: You cannot create, access, or update any UI element from a non-UI thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things you need to fix

```
public void RequestConnection(object username) // changed parameter type
{
    if (username == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(username));

    if (!(username is string))
        throw new InvalidCastException("Expect string");// give proper message

    string serverRsp = client.Connect(username.ToString());
    if (serverRsp.Equals("SUCCESS"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Signed In", "Welcome", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        clientConnected = true;

        //this is require to solve cross-thread operation
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate ()
            {
                frmSignIn.Close();
            }));
        else
            frmSignIn.Close();
    }
}
```

you need to get MdiParent in Form Load Event and remove from Constructor.

Your child form load event/ or use Parent changed Event

```
private void FrmLogin_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmParent = (MainForm)this.MdiParent;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, while this works to execute the thread, the sign in form is not actually closing, so it doesn't seem like its executing frmSignIn

Comment: Hi... sorry to say. I am not able to understand your comment. Can you please explain the isse which you are still facing?

Comment: If my answer completely satisfied your question please mark it as accepted answer. This will help others to find answer rather than checking all anwers in the thread.

Comment: Thank you I had just thought that there was something missing in the answer since the form wasn't closing, but I found out it was due to an unrelated problem (the Connect process was never finishing because it was stuck waiting for a response from the server). Your answer worked

Comment: Good..I tested it before send. Are you facing any other issue you can raise it. I will to solve by my best. Happy coding bro..

Answer (score 0):

The [ParametrizedThreadStart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart?view=netcore-3.1) delegate actually takes an object as parameter.

So you must provide it a method that takes an object as parameter, not as string. In your method you will receive the object, check that it is a string then convert it to a string.

Comment: How do I handle returns from the method? My Connect method returns a string, and my program reacts according to the contents of that string. I can't store that returned value if I call the method from a subthread like thread.Start(username)

Comment: @Elmambo2194 What you are asking is a different question. I suggest you start reading some documentation on how threads work in C#. If you need a return value, use Tasks instead. But start with reading documentation on how all of that works.